# Problem with formatting go code in vscode editor

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gofmt

In a fresh `VSCode 1.52.1`,  I have installed Go extention by `Go Team at Google v0.19.1` as well as the suggested go packages but the auto format at save does not work as it should.

`go version go1.14.6 linux/amd64`

In settings.json I have

```
{
    "go.addTags": {
        "template": "tmpl"
    },
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
    "emmet.preferences": {
    
    },
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.overwriteGoplsMiddleware": {
    
    }
}
```

I used to have a nice autoformat (`goftm`) effect before on another vscode editor, but I don't have access to that machine and I don't remember what where the exact extensions there. so I'm not sure what is missing here,and appreciate your hints.

Comment: I remoed that, but the problem persists.

Comment: I found my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71413582/69002 which could probably be marked as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VScode format as save not work for Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688646/vscode-format-as-save-not-work-for-golang)

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to `settings.json` fixed it for me:

```json
  "[go]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go"
    },
```