# VScode format as save not work for Golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and developing a go project via remote-ssh. However, the format on save does not work. I found it works on the normal project without git. If I remove the `.git`, it will work as expected. Does anyone have some advice for me?

The version of the environment is as follows:

1. vscode 1.63.2
2. go 1.17.6
3. remote machine Ubuntu 20.04
4. go extension v0.30.0

Comment: what's your setting like? if you see the language server trace (
see https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#collect-gopls-information), are there  format request/response messages log?

Comment: @hana Thank you.  I've looked the output log. There is no format related log. Here is the configuration of vscode 
```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "go.alternateTools": {
        // "dlv": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/dlv-sudo.sh",
        // "dlv-dap": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/dlv-dap-sudo.sh"
    },
    "go.languageServerFlags": [
        "-rpc.trace"
    ],
    "gopls": {
        "verboseOutput": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue recently, auto format would only work on projects without a .git directory. What solved the issue for me was to change Format On Save Mode from `modificationsIfAvailable` to `file`. Since I prefer `modificationsIfAvailable` over `file` for everything, I changed to have `formatOnSaveMode` to `file` only for go source files with:

```
 "[go]": {
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have my top-level set to `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable"` to avoid reformatting entire files for small edits. Looks like the golang extension doesn't know what to do with that mode.

Answer (score 5):

Try to format your code manually by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` to open Command Palette and select Format Document. If your file is being properly formatted without any issues, it means there is something wrong in `formatOnSave` settings.

Choose a default formatter instead of null. like this :

```
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
```

Uninstall other formatters one by one to see if anything causes the conflict.

Try to make it Language specific.

For better understanding refer this link : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108447

About Git Specific:

It may be the case that you are running `Git Atom`. Atom is a desktop application, so may be causing problems in accessing the remote installation path.Try installing `Git Repo`.

Also make sure `Go: Install/Update Tools` are up-to-date.